# javascript avoid enter key press

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to detect an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press event when a button has been clicked.
I'm new in javascript and don't know the good way to go...

HTML:

```
<div id="div"> Only execute javascript on click, not enter key press </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#div").click(function () {

   /* IF ENTER KEY PRESSED, RETURN FALSE */

   $("#div").keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked');
      }
   });

  /* Div has been clicked, continue code... */

});
```

This doesn't work...
Maybe there is a better way:

```
$("#div").MOUSE_CLICK_EVENT(function () {});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery trigger() and stopPropagation() on keydown event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730657/jquery-trigger-and-stoppropagation-on-keydown-event)

Comment: Is it even possible to have a keypress on a non-input field?

Comment: @putvande Of course it is, window, document, <button>, <a> links, anything with a tabIndex that gets focus...

Comment: Apparently yes... The div is inside a form. Maybe I should post more detailed code?

Comment: @skyline3000 alright, fair enough, but OP doesn't have `tabindex` on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, you need `stopPropagation` in addition to `preventDefault`, and you should be listening for the `keydown` event rather than `keypress`.

The pure JavaScript way to do this is:

```
document.getElementById('div').onkeydown = function (evt) {
    if (evt.which === 13) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
};

document.getElementById('div').onclick = function (evt) {
    // do whatever you want here
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to stopPropagation like:

```
$('#div').keydown(function(event){
  if (event.which == '13') {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

> **[stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

try this if still needs anybody. Quick solution.

```
$("form").keypress(function(e) {
  //Enter key
   if (e.which == 13) {
   return false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to consider 3 key events: keydown, keypress and keyup.

```
    $("#ID").keydown (function (e) {
        if ( e.key == 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#ID").keyup (function (e) {
        if (e.key  == 'Enter') {
           e.preventDefault();
           e.stopPropagation();
           return false;
        }
    });

    $("#ID").keypress (function (e) {
        if (e.key  == 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });
```